# Check all the value in table and return one value oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I have below query which i want use in stored procedure and which is returning the status with value 0 or 1 or 2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CHECK
    (NAME IN VARCHAR2, IN_ID IN NUMBER,
     IN_STATUS OUT NUMBER)
AS
    CURSOR CHK_STATUS IS
        select STATUS
        from   TEST_LOG
        where  NAME = 'TT'
        and    ID = 19
        and    CHK_DATE >= to_date( TRUNC ( SYSDATE - 1 , 'MM' ) , 'YYYYMMDD' ) 
        and    CHK_DATE < to_date ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE), 'YYYYMMDD' );

BEGIN

    FOR CHK_STAT IN CHK_STATUS
    LOOP
        IF CHK_STAT.STATUS = 0
        THEN
            IN_STATUS := 0;  
        ELSE
            IF CHK_STAT.STATUS = 1
            THEN
                IN_STATUS := 1;
            ELSE
                IN_STATUS := 2;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

END TEST_CHECK;
```

But I want to use logic such that if any of the status from this query returns 2 then it should return as 2. If all the status returns 0 then only return 0. If all the status return 1 then only return 1. If status return between 0 and 1 then return 1. If status return between 1 and 2 then return 2.

So instead of returning too many values I want to restrict the result to only one value status which I want to pass as OUT paramter to another function. I have written above procedure but it's not giving expected output. I am not sure whether I need to use cursor or writing just query instead will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CEIL` function when returning your value, i.e. instead of this statement :

```
IF (CHK_STAT.STATUS =0) 
THEN
  IN_STATUS := 0;  
else if (CHK_STAT.STATUS =1) 
THEN
  IN_STATUS := 1;
else 
  IN_STATUS := 2;

END IF;
```

Just use

```
IN_STATUS := CEIL(CHK_STAT.STATUS);
```

`CEIL` means `ceiling` as name implies, rounds up to consecutive bigger integer,
`i.e. ceil(0)->0, ceil(0.5)->1, ceil(1)->1, ceil(1.3)->2, ceil(2)->2`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the biggest status returned as an integer so something like this should work:

`Select MAX(CEIL(STATUS))
 FROM TEST_LOG
 where SYS_DB_NAME = 'TT' and ENTITY_ID = 19
 AND CHK_DATE >= to_date( TRUNC ( SYSDATE - 1 , 'MM' ) , 'YYYYMMDD' ) 
   AND CHK_DATE < to_date ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE), 'YYYYMMDD' );`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use the code below,

```
FOR CHK_STAT IN CHK_STATUS
LOOP
    IF CHK_STAT.STATUS > IN_STATUS OR IN_STATUS IS NULL THEN
        IN_STATUS := CEIL(CHK_STAT.STATUS);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: i dont think i required for loop here which can reduce performance of my performance right _

Comment: ah, ok, but i just modified a part of your code above, you still have a choice not to use the code i gave